# How do I find the correct *.class file to run Java application?

Tags: java, linux, performance, compilation, debian

Consider a scenario that I've been given a **Java project** that I don't know anything about and I have to **compile it and run it**.

I'd like some solution which will allow me to **compile and run** any program as fast as possible **without knowing anything about the project**.

**What have I tried:**

To do so I'm using following procedure to compile the program.

```
# compile *.java files into *.class files
javac -d . -encoding UTF-8 *.java
```

To run the program I'm using following command but it wants **package and class** where the method main is. Which I don't know.

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 package.class
```

I found out that it is possible to check for it using loop and `javap` so I wrote a simple shell script to **automatically compile the program, find the package and class where the main method is and run it**:

```
containsMain()
{
    if javap -public $1 | fgrep 'public static void main(' > /dev/null; then
        echo $1 | sed 's/^.\///' | cut -f 1 -d '.' | tr / .
    fi
}

for classfile in */*.class; do
    runclass=$(containsMain $classfile);
    if [ "$runclass" ]; then
        break
    fi
done

java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 $runclass
```

**What problems have I discovered:**

This works as intended but the `javap` is **slow** as hell. It **takes 1.2 sec for each file to check**. So in the worst scenario it has to loop over all the files to find the method main which may take a long time.

**Another solution?**

I was thinking to write some regular expressions to **search the *.java files for the method main** and **parse the class and package** in which it is placed. Which is not as easy as it seems to be cause the **main method can be written multiple ways** (modificators). It can be **written in comments, strings** etc. There can be even **multiple classes in the file**.

But I'm kinda scared if this is a correct solution and I'd like to know that there is no other way before I'll start doing something like this.

Thanks for any advice :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can bundle your java application into jar, then it is easy to find main class from Manifest file.

```
    JarFile j = new JarFile(new File("jarfile.jar"));
    String mainClassName = j.getManifest().getMainAttributes().getValue("Main-Class");
```

Comment: To bundle the application into *.jar I'd firstly need to know the package and class where the main method is to generate that *.jar file. And if I had the *.jar file I'd just run it without needing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

> Consider a scenario that I've been given a Java project that I don't know anything about and I have to compile it and run it.

There's no (single) solution as there may be multiple `main` methods and this makes sense (imagine Zip.java and Unzip.java).

> I was thinking to write some regular expressions to search the *.java files for the method main and parse the class and package in which it is placed.

As the first filter, I'd grep for the word main (`"\bmain\b"`). This alone could be good enough for making 1.2 sec for making `javap` acceptable.

---

You could also add your own main-containing class, which tries to call the `main` method of all *other* classes reflectively until it succeeds. This loads all classes, which takes some time, but surely less than `javap` does.

Comment: Good point with multiple `main` methods. Actually I want to compile and run the Java program under 2 seconds. Compilation takes already 2.4 sec. So I don't want to run the `javap` program since it takes so long. I was wondering if there is really no way to easily run the application without searching which file to run.

Answer (score 0):

IF there is a single main method you can do it with putting a launcher Main class (e.g. in the default package) of the sources to be compiled and then start that launcher Main class instead.
This launcher Main class could then inspect the ClassLoader look for all classes and find with reflection if one of them has a main method. A sample code could look like this:

```
public class Main {

private static boolean found = false;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ClassLoader classLoader = Main.class.getClassLoader();
        if (classLoader instanceof URLClassLoader) {
            URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) classLoader;
            URL[] urLs = urlClassLoader.getURLs();
            for (URL url : urLs) {
                File classesDir = new File(url.toURI());
                Path classesPath = classesDir.toPath();
                int lenOfStartPath = classesDir.getAbsolutePath().length();
                Files.walkFileTree(classesPath, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                    @Override
                    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                            throws IOException {
                        File file = path.toFile();
                        if (file.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                            String className = file.getAbsolutePath().substring(lenOfStartPath + 1);
                            className = className.substring(0,className.length() - ".class".length());
                            className = className.replace('\\', '.');
                            className = className.replace('/','.');
                            if (!Main.class.getName().equals(className)) {
                                try {
                                    Class<?> potentialMainClass = Class.forName(className);
                                    Method mainMethod = potentialMainClass.getMethod("main", new Class[] {String[].class});
                                    found = true;
                                    try {
                                        mainMethod.invoke(null, (Object) args);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    return FileVisitResult.TERMINATE;
                                } catch (NoSuchMethodException|ClassNotFoundException e) {
                                    //Class not found of has no main method.
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            System.err.println("No proper class found");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Of course, you probably do not know, what arguments you should pass to the main method, so it also only works for main classes without arguments.